# Voltage across a resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

When i was doing the practice problems, I found the following problem: [image]

I was able to solve for everything except for V4. 
When I looked at the solution manual,solution was as follows: 
 
Use KVL: V4 = 3*2 + V3, (V3 was obtained from previous steps)

However, I'm confused because they wrote that it is a KVL equation, but it did not include 8 ohm resistor. I thought that in order to write a KVL equation, the entire loop must be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're overcomplicating it. Since you already know $v_3$, all you need to do is calculate the voltage drop across the resistor with $3\Omega$. Since the current is $2A$, the voltage drop is $3*2$. Thus, $v_4$ should be 6 volts higher than $v_3$. This is a manifestation of KVL.

**(more in depth if you are still confused)**

At the core of KVL, it's that all around a loop the sum of the voltage drops must be 0. This is perhaps why you are thinking that you must look around a whole loop to get $v_4$. In truth, you already have without knowing it. Knowing $v_3$ means that you know the voltage drop from that point until "the end of your loop." The end of your loop can be defined wherever you'd like, but it most likely is defined to be at the positive terminal of the battery. Thus, you know the voltage all the way from the $v_3$ point of the circuit to the positive terminal of the battery. All that is left is the small portion of the loop with the $2\Omega$ resistor in it. After calculating that voltage drop, you have effectively calculated the sum of the voltage drops around the loop to be 0.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what you meant by the positive terminal of the battery. You are saying that the voltage from V3 to the current source 2A will be the same? But what about the 8 ohm resistor? There should be a voltage drop across it, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong loop. You do not know that 2A of current are traveling across the 8 ohm resistor.  But the loop you should be looking at is the bigger, rectangular one (going to the negative terminal of the 8 Volt battery). There are no resistors between it and V4. Therefore the only voltage drop separating V3 and V4 is the voltage drop across the 2 ohm resistor.

Comment: If you knew the current going through the 8 ohm resistor, you could use the loop you're talking about, but unfortunately that information is not given, so you must pick a different loop. Honestly, think of it in terms of voltage drops instead of whole loops - it's a lot easier. V4 - (2A*3 ohms) = V3 should be the equation that immediately comes to mind for a voltage drop here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving for $v_4$ if you know $v_3$ is to use KCL for node $v_4$ by summing the currents **into** the node

$2+ \dfrac{v_3-v_4}{3}=0$

On rearranging this gives the KVL equation

$v_3 + 3\times 2 - v_4 =0$

In terms of a potential diagram starting at the zero volt end of the 8 ohm resistor it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I never thought of applying KCL for a node like V4. Thank you !